# Is there any harm using a pseudo-prime endorsed by a probablistic test like Miller-Rabin in RSA?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers

In RSA, the decryption exponent $d$ is typically calculated as $$d= e^{-1} \bmod{(p-1)(q-1)}$$ or $$d = e^{-1} \bmod \operatorname{lcm}{(p-1, q-1)}$$

where $p$ and $q$ are often randomly selected numbers passing probabilistic primality tests such as Miller-Rabin. Usually, the more rounds of these tests, the more confident the key generation algorithm has on the primality of these factors.

But **Q**: does it actually cause harm if the supposed prime factors are actually pseudo-prime? More specifically, Miller-Rabin pseudo-primes? Since:

- the candidates for testing are generated using an RNG usually not under the control of any adversary,
- pseudo-primes satisfy the conditions for the formula that computes $d$,
- the modulus remains unfactorable, at least theoretically.

Comment: Highly related [Is there a pseudo message that will encrypt and decrypt correctly if one of the primes is a pseudo prime in RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83523/18298)

Comment: If an adversary can't control the prime candidates and the modulus is unfactorable, you should be safe. However if an adversary is able to pick the prime candidates, you can case a lot of havoc.
This paper might be interesting in that regard:
https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/749.pdf